# jQuery post method fails if request is sent too fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the below drop down list in my **`_Layout.cshtml`**

```
@Html.DropDownList("myList", 
new SelectList(apps, "AppId", "Name", ViewBag.AppId),
new {@class = "mySelectBox", onchange = "updateAppLayout(this);"})
```

And the javscript function is in seperate .js file as :

```
function updateAppLayout(sel) {
var name = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
var appId = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
var data = { "appname": name, "appId": appId };
var url = "/Test/TestLayout";    
$.post(url, data)
    .done(function(msg) {})
    .fail(function (xhr, status, error) {          

    });
}
```

Whenever i change the drop down value too fast the **`.fail()`** method is called. I put a console inside the **`.fail()`** method for the **sel** value and it gives this value - > **`select#myList.mySelectBox`**
But if i have the console just before the **`$.post`** method I get the dropdownlist.
Not sure whats wrong here.
PS: I do not want to use **`setTimeout`**

Comment: How is it actually failing?  What's the error?

Comment: @David : Inside the `.fail()` method if i check the values of **xhr.statusText** and **error** properties I get only stringvalue as **'error'**

Answer (score 0):

I would disable the select list while loading, this way you can ensure that it will only get new value on return of the first one

```
function updateAppLayout(sel) {
var name = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
var appId = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById("myList").disabled = true;

var data = { "appname": name, "appId": appId };
var url = "/Test/TestLayout";    
$.post(url, data)
    .done(function(msg) {
document.getElementById("myList").disabled = false;
//do something 
})
    .fail(function (xhr, status, error) {          

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Munzer but could be the root cause of the problem as your answer is more like a work around

Comment: you didn't say what it is the error, how to know what is the cause if we don't know what it is

Comment: As I said whenever I change the dropdown values too fast then sometimes the `fail()` method is being called and if i check the values of **xhr.statusTex**t and **error** properties I get only string value as 'error'